# Qt without Xcode

Tags: macos, qt

Is it possible to use Qt and Qt Creator on MacOS with Command Line Tools only, i.e. without installing the whole Xcode?

I'm asking because I'm getting "Project ERROR: Could not resolve SDK Path for 'macosx'" and all the solutions I read ask for full Xcode.

Comment: What do you mean by "Command Line Tools only"? You can simply install Qt for Mac and start using it with Qt Creator.

Comment: @Azeem Qt for Mac does not come with a compiler, it uses clang provided by Apple. It is possible to get the compiler in two ways: install whole XCode or just the command line tools. Apparently Qt gets confused when pursuing the second option...

Comment: I didn't know that. What you are saying is that this [download package for Qt 5.9.0](http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.9/5.9.0/qt-opensource-mac-x64-5.9.0.dmg) won't have compiler with it, right?

Comment: @Azeem Correct.

Comment: Right. Thanks, Ecir! :) So, the solution is to update XCode and then use Qt Creator?

Comment: @Azeem I did not update it, I only have the Tools.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146950/discussion-between-azeem-and-ecir-hana).

Comment: With gcc compiler you can avoid even Apple "Command line tools" but then you going to need to set up gdb debugger with some permissions.

Comment: @EcirHana Did you find a way to install Qt without full Xcode package? I've been searching for days and can't find anything that works. Really don't want to waste 5gb of HDD space on Xcode9

Comment: @Braden Unfortunately no, I had to install the whole Xcode.

Comment: There is a [workaround with fixing a couple Qt scripts](https://forum.qt.io/post/368153) *only for Desktop builds*. Unfortunately it didn't work in my case (MacOS 10.9 + Qt 5.7.1) - `xcrun --sdk macosx --show-sdk-path` prints empty path :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question when I wanted to install Qt on an old MacBook Air that can't run the version of macOS that XCode now requires.

I found this [document detailing how to install Qt without XCode](https://gist.github.com/nonwill/0ab9ab5c6a2b0027c3f968d6f1151da2).

It does complain about XCode not being present, but as the document notes you can ignore that and proceed anyway.

(Note: solution didn't solve *my* problem for a couple obscure reasons, but I'm leaving the answer because it is an additional option not yet mentioned.)